# How to insert additional supplementary .pdf help files to packages besides automatically-created-.pdf during build/install process in R?

Tags: r, pdf, package

I used `roxygen` package. It produced .Rd files for me. I can produce .pdf of my package via " `R CMD Rd2pdf causfinder/`" from Windows command line; or, I can produce .pdf during build/install process via "`roxygenize("causfinder")`; `build("causfinder")`; `install("causfinder")`". That is OK.

I want to add some supplementary .pdf help files (that I created outside of R) to my package other than the one that is produced via above techniques. These supplementary .pdf files include the detailed mathematical theory and lots of samples of the functions of my package which illustrate the usage of the functions via various plots, graphs, etc.

What is the proper way of adding these supplementary .pdf files to a package?

Can I produce a folder (like "supplementary") in R's working directory and put these supplementary .pdf files there before build/install process; 
and (if so) does this have an effect to CRAN pass, negative?

That is to say, I wanna add these .pdf files but on the other hand, I do not want any trouble during CRAN pass phase due to these additional .pdf files.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the key word here is 'vignette', to which you can also provide the raw TeX files if you fancy that. Also, if you want to integrate R code with TeX, there's R Sweave. They are usually located in /pckgName/vignettes/ path. It shouldn't be a problem if they're PDF for CRAN pass. You can run local CRAN-type checks to see if there's anything weird in your report. See discussion at http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/what-is-a-vignette-td2302242.html and http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Writing-package-vignettes and http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-exts/R-exts_23.html

Comment: You solved 50% of problem: R packages can include documents in arbitrary format. The std location for these is subdirectory inst/doc of a source package in R's working directory, contents will be copied to subdirectory doc (of R's library directory) when the package is installed. Pointers from package help indices to the installed documents are automatically created. NOW: causfinder/doc/index.html of R's library:
Vignettes from package 'causfinder': package contains no vignette meta-information.
Other files in the doc directory: TheoryOfcausfinder.pdf How to open Theory..pdf within R console?